# Running parallel jobs with --array parameter in slum

Tags: slurm

I'm trying to learn the slurm system, but I'm having some trouble understanding.  I'm trying to run a bunch of jobs in parallel using the --array parameter in sbatch.  I would like the jobs to be spread out over multiple nodes, but it seems like they are all running on the same node, given the time stamps.

The sbatch command I am using:

```
sbatch  -N 10 -a 0-19 --cpus-per-task 10 test.sh
```

The test.sh file being run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#SBATCH -o test_%a.out
#SBATCH -p all.q
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00

srun --cpus-per-task 10 -k --exclusive --ntasks 1 -N 1 echo "`date ` array_index: $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID node: $SLURM_NODEID requested nodes: $SLURM_NNODES  `sleep 3`"
```

The output files:

```
Thu Feb 12 19:51:28 UTC 2015 array_index: 0 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:45 UTC 2015 array_index: 10 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:45 UTC 2015 array_index: 11 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:49 UTC 2015 array_index: 12 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:49 UTC 2015 array_index: 13 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:52 UTC 2015 array_index: 14 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:52 UTC 2015 array_index: 15 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:56 UTC 2015 array_index: 16 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:56 UTC 2015 array_index: 17 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:59 UTC 2015 array_index: 18 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:59 UTC 2015 array_index: 19 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:28 UTC 2015 array_index: 1 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:32 UTC 2015 array_index: 2 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:32 UTC 2015 array_index: 3 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:35 UTC 2015 array_index: 4 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:35 UTC 2015 array_index: 5 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:39 UTC 2015 array_index: 6 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:39 UTC 2015 array_index: 7 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:42 UTC 2015 array_index: 8 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
Thu Feb 12 19:51:42 UTC 2015 array_index: 9 node: 0 requested nodes: 10
```

Comment: Why don't you add a `$(hostname -s)` in your `echo` line to actually test whether or not they all run on the same node?

Answer (score 0):

SLURM's job array support first completes one batch job, and then proceeds to the second. So here, the first batch script (lets say `$JOB_ID.0`) would be finished (which only has one srun command), then the second one would start etc. These would just work in serial.

You could have one batch job, and have multiple srun commands in that job. That would span the multiple nodes like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that spreads an array job across nodes... the trick here is to assign 1 task to several cores (in the script below, we use 16 cores... so a 64-core machine will get 4 tasks - you can alter this as needed). I called the file "job_array.sbatch" and it can be invoked using "sbatch -a 1-20 job_array.sbatch" (or whatever array elements you would like to use):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# invoke using sbatch -a 1-20 job_array.sbatch
#
#SBATCH -n 16 # this requests 16 cores per task, which will effectively spread the job across nodes
#SBATCH -N 1 # on one machine
#SBATCH -J job_array
#SBATCH -t 00:00:30
#
date
echo ""
echo "job_array.sbatch"
echo "  Run several instances of a job using a single script."
#
#  Each job has values of certain environment variables.
#
echo "  SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID = " $SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID
echo "  SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID = " $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
echo "  SLURM_JOB_ID = " $SLURM_JOB_ID
echo "  SLURM_NODELIST = " $SLURM_NODELIST
#
#  Terminate.
#
echo ""
echo "job_array.sbatch:"
echo "  Normal end of execution."
date
#
exit
```